# AWS Route 53 - How to route traffic to Load balancer including context path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a domain company.com, in route 53 I successfully created sub-domain sales.company.com. I have a load balancer running a service with a context root path(e.g. rootpath). I can access the app using loadbalancerdns/rootpath. I tried to create an A record in route 53 to point sales.company.com traffic to loadbalancerdns/rootpath but it does not allow it but if I point to loadbalancerdns then it works and I can access the service using sales.company.com/rootpath.

My question is it possible to route sales.company.com to loadbalancerdns/rootpath ? If not how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't do this**. Route53 is DNS provider and it does not have a concept of an url path. You can only create records to full odmains `sales.company.com` (not `sales.company.com/url-path` or IP addresses.

You can create path based routing in your application load balancer using **listener rules**, or front your load balancer with CloudFront. The CloudFront allows you to respond differently to different paths in your url.